# What happens to other views in Universal Image Loader

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I am learning Universal Image Loader lib and I ran into some learners doubt for which I can't seem to find any documentation. My question is, that in a very long gridview I am displaying images along with some other text and I know the images are getting cached on disk. But what about the img descriptions, counts, votes, other texts in view. Are they getting first re-downloaded everytime and then getting inflated I scroll back up or they getting cached too?  Will it cause any performance issue?

Comment: in your adapter every time you create view means you are not use ViewHolder ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server would give text descriptions along with image url. The image would be loaded by UIL with the url, right? All of them could be put in `ArrayList` sequentially, it will be consumed by Adapter, and finally the adapter will be plugged into `GridView`.

Texts will be holded in local database or in-memory by `ArrayList`. So, it does not need to be re-downloaded as data already in device memory. Generally, it does not give performance issue as text input/output is very timid overload than displaying image process. Your array can be more than a length of hundreds and it also does not give performance issue in current devices.

Note that, UIL utilizes image cache not only on the disk, but also in-memory.